# How to create a C class on Eclipse

Tags: c, class, eclipse-3.6

I am learning how to program in C and using Eclipse helios that can compile both C and C++. When I tried to create a class, it always says creating a C++ class but not C. How do I create a C class with some default setting(#include, #include, etc.) on it?

Comment: there is no such thing in C

Comment: Yeah, no classes in C.

Comment: If C does not have a class, how do I program with it on Eclipse?

Comment: You umm.. write code without using classes.

Comment: You will have to write code in (and compile it as) C++ if you want to use classes.  While C and C++ are similar languages, only C++ supports object-oriented programming directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C does not have classes.

The capability of your IDE to compiler both C and C++ doesn't mean that it can transfer the constructs and concepts of C++ into a C program. It means that you can either compile a C program, or a C++ one.

Comment: If C does not have a class, how do I program on it on Eclipse?

Comment: @StevenChan you don't.  You make a C++ program instead.

Comment: @dbush do you mean I can create a C++ class and work on it? Is it compatible with C syntax?

Comment: No. You have to work on a C++ project, if you want classes.